# Student's T-Test: Difference of means is within $95\%$ CI yet p-value $\ll0.05$

Tags: r, confidence-interval, t-test, p-value

I have some data about heart rate (`thalach`) stratified by location (`siteCVA`). I used a Student's T-test to see if there was a difference in heart rate between locations. The image below shows the test I ran in R and the results

[image: Here's the basic R code I ran.]

The difference of means is $\sim27$, which falls into the $95\%$ CI, yet the p-value is less than $2.2\times10^{-16}$. What does this mean? By definition, shouldn't the p-value $> 0.05$ if it's within the $95\%$ CI?

Comment: The difference in means will always be in the middle of the interval, since the interval is centered there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If your confidence interval contains 0 then there is not a significant difference. The 95% confidence interval you have does not contain 0 - therefore it is significant.

Anytime you're looking at difference in means, proportions or anything...you're trying to see if 0 is in the confidence interval. If it isn't, then it's significant.  Does that make sense?

Comment: I think we can  test for difference in means to a nonzero constant?

Comment: Sure. We can test whether the difference is equal (or greater than, less than, etc) to any constant - but in this case, the question was whether or not the difference between the two populations was 0. Had the question been "The true difference in population means does not equal 3" then you would have to see if 3 was in the CI.